# для работы с Python ищу Android приложение которое позволяет использовать внешние файлы

Tags: android, python

хочется найти Android приложение которое позволить читать информацию из текстового файла или импортировать функции и данные. Сейчас пользуюсь Pydroid 3, но в нем таких функций нет.

Comment: установил но даже не смог запустить. там все сложно, а тратить много времени не хочется

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте [Kivy](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.kivy.pygame). Он позволит дополнительно ещё и использовать графические возможности, вплоть до написания игр. Минус - нет встроенного редактора. Но его заменит любой текстовый редактор на андроид.